# different devices same pixel with acting differntly

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am currently working on a template for a webpage and I'm currently working on the responsiveness for it. I have the desktop version and the mobile phone versions working just fine. The problem that I'm having with it right now is I'm trying to make a version for tablets. The "tablet" I'm using right now is a surface pro which has a 96 dpi. My desktop has and older 1080 monitor. So when I open chrome up with dev tools on the surface the pixel width is the same or close to my desktop but is looking completely different. Text that is on a single line on the desktop is on two lines for the surface and not all is showing. The reason this is an issue is that this is the header of the page. At full width on the surface it's acting more like half width on the desktop. I thought it might be because the screen for the surface is higher DPI on the surface but not sure. Is this what is causing this and if so how do you fix it. Setting a media query of say 800px for tablet works for say desktop and some tablets but doesn't seem to be working for something like a surface. So is there a different way to set up width? I have code of the site but I don't think any of it would be helpful. If needed let me know.

Comment: can you share an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vh`(viewport height) for height and `vw`(viewport width) for width, it uses percentage of the window. `100vh` would use 100% of the window height and `100vw` would use 100% of the window width. It's better than using pixels and requires less work to make the page responsive, pixels are inconsistent and break easily.

Comment: ok Thank you for the extremely quick response. I'll give that a shot. Thank you again.